# Pycharm, can not find Python version 2.7.11

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

[image][image]I installed Python 2.7.11 on this Mac, and from terminal Python 2.7.11 can be started. However, 
From the interpreter of Pycharm (2016.1 version) , there is no Python 2.7.11.

Any suggestions ? Thanks

PS:I successfully did this on one Mac, but for some reason I cannot make it on another Mac... odd..

Comment: Did you click on the three dots to the right of the drop down to point to the location of the Python 2.7.11 install?

Comment: Do you have `export PATH="$(brew -prefix)/$PATH"` in your `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I think the label of the "2.7.6" is just wrong. You could try to print the python version in code with that interpreter if you'd like to check that isn't actually "2.7.11"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you cannot find from the list, you can add it manually,

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html?origin=old_help

you need to specify the python path in the add local dialogue. you mentioned that you can start python 2.7.11 from your terminal, then type 'which python' in your terminal and get your python path. copy paste this path to your PyCharm "add Local" . e.g:

```
bash-3.2$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but not working. Python 2.7.11 is not there from the list of "add local".

Comment: I think when you click 'add local', a dialog will popup to let you choose the path of python executable from the file system.  if you still cannot find it, it may helps if you can add a screen capture of 'add local'

Comment: Thanks Guoliang ! -- Please take a look at the screenshot added.

Comment: you may need to find your python path and add it.  I updated the my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the python in the first image you uploaded. It will work.