# Tensorflow not working on Python 3.7, Mac OS, and Pycharm

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, python-3.7

Attempting to run tensorflow a Mac, using python 3.7 as well as PyCharm and receiving [image] where `module tensorflow has no attribute app`, at the following.

[image]

I've run through a number of potential solutions. Following the instructions provided on this question: [Installing tensorflow on Pycharm (Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998018/installing-tensorflow-on-pycharm-mac). I've managed to successfully create a virtual-env in which I installed the tensorflow package however this folder contains
[nothing but the **init**.py and pycache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SIqF.png) and the error remains.

[image]

I've also tried copying the contents of the tensorflow GitHub repo directly into this folder but it results in an `ImportError`.

Not sure what the issue is. Should I switch to python 2.7?

Comment: It will be much helpful if you post some of your code and error.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I dont think the error has to do with code however as I'm attempting to make this repo code work: https://github.com/jaehong-yoon93/DEN

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6, not Python 2.7. BTW, Python 2 will become dead very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7 is still unsupported as of this moment by tensorflow.